# iTunes - New TestFlight Beta testing build status?

Tags: ios, ios8, testflight

[image]

I have uploaded build on TestFlight beta iTunes. Its status is showing "Created" to me instead of Processing . Does any one know about build status "Created" ? What does this mean ? Does apple need to review ?

Comment: Any answer that should be accepted?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait a bit, Apple is still finishing the touches on uploading and processing your build from the image you attached. You'll be able to tick a selector to the activated position (green) next to beta testing for the version when they are done. Then you'll be able to test it yourself and after they review it (in my experience it takes about a day) then you can invite external testers.

Check this image of one of my apps for reference. [image]

Answer (score 0):

The developer build versions will be made available to testers only after review by Apple.

In my case the builds were approved within 8 hours and i was able to invite the testers to test the build.